# Reading a specific input format in C

Tags: c, input

I need to read all N numbers in a line in an array where N is unknown. When a newline is encountered, read the next X numbers in another array. X is also unknown.

The input is in the format:-

1 2 3 4 5 .. to N  (store in array A)

1 2 3 4 .. to X (store in array B).

How to take the input for this case?

Comment: Use read, fread, getc, fgetc, or fgets.  (Do not use gets!) Realloc as necessary.

Comment: homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: Removed C++ tag, the answer is totally different if you use C++

Comment: no, this is not a homework. I am starting out with some acm problems, and I am having problem with reading the input for one of the questions.

Comment: I was trying this out with sscanf, after reading the line into a string.

Comment: IIRC, the UVA site on ACM problems details how to handle input (in all supported languages). Did you refer to that site? Or their board: http://online-judge.uva.es/board/? Here is a sample they have on their site: http://online-judge.uva.es/problemset/data/p100.c.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
while ( scanf(" %d%c", &num, &ch) == 2 )
{
    if ( ch =='\n') break;
    // to do :: store or whatever you want 
}
```

it read untill get newline.